# Sitecore Language Embedding multiple sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm looking to run two sites off one Sitecore install.

The first site will only be in UK English therefore I won't include the language in the file path. `languageEmbedding=never`

The second site will be in multiple languages and I need to include the language in the file path. `languageEmbedding=always`

Is there a way I can define multiple link managers and configure the sites to use a specific link manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the best way was to create a custom link manager that supports both scenarios. Then have a supporting config setting which defines whether the language is embedded.

```
public class LanguageLinkProvider : LinkProvider
{
    public override string GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions urlOptions)
    {
        urlOptions.SiteResolving = Configuration.Settings.Rendering.SiteResolving;
        string sites = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmbedLanguageInUrl"];

        var splitSites = new List<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sites))
            splitSites = sites.Split(';').ToList();

        if (splitSites.Contains(urlOptions.Site.Name))
            urlOptions.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always;
        else
            urlOptions.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Never;

        return base.GetItemUrl(item, urlOptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope, not by default.
But the LinkManager is overrideable. Probably you can change the behavior by selecting a different config per site and coding this into an overriden LinkManager.

Comment: Great solution! The only one I can think of myself.