# In Sitecore, what is the page at /si for?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

In the Sitecore sites I'm working on (6.5 and 6.6), I've noticed that all the sites have a page at /si that is the same as the home page, but with the content missing/hidden.

Does anyone else have a website with this page? Does anyone know what it is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Chinese version of the home page. The content is missing as there are no Chinese language specific fields filled with data, but the page itself may come from `Standard values`.

Most probably your `LinkManager` in **Sitecore.config** has the value of `languageEmbedding` property set to **asNeeded** or **always**.

Switching to **never** would solve this issue (as long as you're not using multilanguage versions of you pages and you need language in the url).

Here are some posts which gives some more input about `LinkManager`:

[Patching the Linkmanager](http://www.mikkelhm.dk/post/2012/11/12/Patching-the-Linkmanager.aspx)

[Sitecore Language Embedding multiple sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570360/sitecore-language-embedding-multiple-sites)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected Sitecore behavior.

You can find the same "pages" with "it", "dk", "de", "se" and so on. 
In the httpRequestBegin pipeline found in web.config you can see that Sitecore language resolver is kicking in before the item resolver does. Hence Sitecore interprets the request as a request for the home page in another language layer and any two-letter ISO code for language will return the home page in that specified language context.

You could implement your own processor before the language resolver if you want to handle requests for specific language codes in certain ways.